# Chromium based browsers crashing when running selenium tests on windows server 2019

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, chromium, windows-server-2019

I have a set of selenium/java tests that I am trying to execute on a remote system running windows server 2019 datacenter.

These tests run fine on my local machine (Windows 10), but on the server, I have issues running my tests in chromium-based browsers.
When I try to run in Chrome or Edge, the browser is started but the screen stays blank, and an icon on the tab indicates that the browser has crashed.
When trying to run on firefox, there are no issues whatsoever.

I am debugging using chrome with the following simplified script, which runs fine on all browsers locally and on the server using firefox:

```
package tests;

import lib.BrowserFactory;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class ChromeTest {

@Test
public void test1() {
    //WebDriver driver = BrowserFactory.createBrowser(BrowserFactory.Browser.CHROME);

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("example.com");

    }

}
```

I am normally getting my browser drivers via a browserfactory that fetches a browserdriver using 'webdrivermanager', but for the sake of debugging, I have tried linking directly to the browserdriver, which gave the same result.

When the browser crashes, I get the following stacktrace after about a minute:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 91.0.4472.101 (af52a90bf87030dd1523486a1cd3ae25c5d76c9b-refs/branch- 
heads/4472@{#1462}) on port 60505
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on 
keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 
500. Message: unknown error: unable to discover open pages
Build info: version: '4.0.0-beta-4', revision: '29f46d02dd'
System info: host: 'PTQ-SH01', ip: '10.0.0.6', os.name: 'Windows Server 2019', os.arch: 
'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.11'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, 
goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], extensions: []}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities 
{browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], extensions: []}}}]

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:84)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:62)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:156)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:162)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:137)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:612)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:244)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:165)
at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:89)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:99)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:86)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:41)
at lib.BrowserFactory.createChromeBrowser(BrowserFactory.java:35)
at lib.BrowserFactory.createBrowser(BrowserFactory.java:29)
at tests.openSite.open(openSite.java:13)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

The chrome version on the server is updated to 91.0.4472.114, which is the latest version and the same as on my local machine. I am also using the latest chromedriver (91.0.4472.101), which should be compatible (proven by the fact that it runs fine locally)

Can anyone help me figure out what the issue is?

Comment: Can you try with ChromeOption option = new ChromeOption();
option.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(option);

Comment: I tried that, and it solved the issue. Thanks! I had heard of that option before, but using it here never came to mind. I did read here and there that this is a bit of a hacky solution, and I am wondering what is actually causing chromium based browsers to fail.

Comment: Glad to know that it's started working, cheers